# Android: Overlay on Android Camera Preview

Tags: android, header, camera

I'm using Camera API and invoking the camera.

I want to display a header (for branding) on the top of the camera preview. The header is  a jpeg image.

Is it possible?  Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My code goes as below.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;
    private Bitmap image2;
    private Bitmap bm;
    public static String imagepath;
    public static int x=1;
    private RdmsDbAdapter dbHelper;
    @Override



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.header);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        //caling new incident
        if(IncidentFormActivity.incident_id == null || IncidentFormActivity.isDisable==true){
            //DBAdapter instance created and connection opened. 
            dbHelper = new RdmsDbAdapter(CameraActivity.this);
            dbHelper.open();

            //setting up flags
            NewIncidentHelper nih = new NewIncidentHelper();
            nih.setUpNewIncident();

            //setting up incident_id
            String Date= IncidentIdGenerator.getDate();
            String Time = IncidentIdGenerator.getTime();

            IncidentFormActivity.incident_id = IncidentIdGenerator.now("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
            dbHelper.executeSQL("insert into incident values ('" + IncidentFormActivity.incident_id
                    + "', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '"+Date+"', '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','"+Time+"')");
            dbHelper.close();
        }

        //calling camera
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);


    }
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    //back key on phone pressed
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            Intent i= new Intent(CameraActivity.this, IncidentFormActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            this.finish();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    //handle response came from camera when the picture is taken.
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100));
                image2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                img.setImageBitmap(image2);
                String incident_ID = IncidentFormActivity.incident_id;
                //l2.addView(img);
                    imagepath="/sdcard/RDMS/"+incident_ID+ x + ".png";
                File file = new File(imagepath);
                try {
                     bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( image2,400, 300, true);
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, ostream);
                    ostream.close(); 
                    //Initialising db class and inserting values
                    dbHelper = new RdmsDbAdapter(CameraActivity.this);
                    dbHelper.open();
                    dbHelper.executeSQL("insert into files values ('"+imagepath+"', '"+IncidentFormActivity.incident_id+"')");
                    dbHelper.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourfirst  error message is "
                                            + e.toString(), 1000).show();
                }
                x++;
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        CameraActivity.this);

                alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.anotherimage));
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                //alert.setMessage("Play or Delete the Video selected");
                //alert.setIcon(R.drawable.vid_red);
                alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent sendingpage = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                          startActivity(sendingpage);

                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent callback = new Intent (CameraActivity.this, IncidentFormActivity.class);
                                startActivity(callback);
                            }
                        });

                alert.show();


            }
            if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
            {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraActivity.this);

                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.areuexit)).setCancelable(
                        false).setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i= new Intent(CameraActivity.this, IncidentFormActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                CameraActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                Intent i= new Intent(CameraActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);                            startActivity(i);
                                CameraActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        });

                builder.show();



            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: by header, do you mean a graphic at the top of the camera app or some sort of watermark-like graphic?

Comment: yes I want to show a graphic on top as header. thanks.

Comment: yes I want to show a graphic on top as header on top of camera preview. Nothing much, I don't even want to alter the image taken. thanks.

Comment: Nice separation of concerns

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use SurfaceView and create a CustomView that will open the camera and you can adjust its size in the xml accordingly. Below is a pseudo code.

**Create a class that extends SurfaceView and open camera inside that**

**CapturePreview.java**

```
public class CapturePreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    public static Bitmap mBitmap;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    static Camera mCamera;

    public CapturePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
    /***
     * 
     *  Take a picture and and convert it from bytes[] to Bitmap.
     *  
     */
    public static void takeAPicture(){  

        Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
            }
        };
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
    }
}
```

**Now you have to include the view that you created using SurfaceView in your xml like this**

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <FrameLayout 
  android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.cam.CapturePreview 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </com.cam.CapturePreview>

  </FrameLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_below="@id/mySurfaceView" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:gravity="center">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/myImageView" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
  </LinearLayout>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you can use this main.xml in any `Acitivty` that will open a camera with a `ImageView`.
Thanks....

Comment: Had to remove `android:layout_below="@id/mySurfaceView"` for the code to work.

Comment: The camera preview is very distorted

Comment: then what's the solution now?

Comment: Check out my sample code forked from Google's Camera2Video with a solution to the depreciation issues. https://github.com/chriscborg/android-Camera2Video

Answer (score 20):

You will have to handle the whole camera preview and taking picture yourself. Take a look at the Samples at `samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview`. You can have your own layout over the preview area and add your graphic to it.

### Sample link

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect#java

Comment: what happened to the link? it seems to redirect. can you relink the correct one?

Comment: broken link 
 updated -
 https://developer.android.com/samples/RuntimePermissionsBasic/src/com.example.android.basicpermissions/camera/CameraPreview.html

Comment: @PavanK your link is broken

Comment: sorry but google updated their api  you can search for it under https://developer.android.com/samples/

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the help of `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <android.view.SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/surface"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/header"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This [camera project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to implement camera preview screen yourself. In theory an overlay can be added to other application by modifying its layout or by creating an overlay window. The first way is impossible to implement and the second way can be implemented I think but it's kind of a hack and a error prone method.

Implementing you own camera activity is not a very difficult task but it's rather challenging. I would recommend you to take a look at the default Camera application. Here's its source code: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera.

Comment: "not a very difficult task but it's rather challenging" Well, which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

look your XML would be like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<android.view.SurfaceView
 android:id="@+id/surface"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ImageView
android:id = "@+id/header"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and for the java code you should extend SurfaceHolder.Callback in your activity and then attach the camera to the surface view like this,its my full code please be careful with bitmaps and canvas that is the tricky part :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
  private Camera camera = null;
  private SurfaceView cameraSurfaceView = null;
  private SurfaceHolder cameraSurfaceHolder = null;
  private boolean previewing = false;
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout;





  private Button btnCapture = null;
  private Button btnsave = null;
  private Button btnshare = null;
  private boolean isSaved=false;
  private boolean isCaptured=false;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerImg);
    relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)
                                       findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
  //  cameraSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480));
    cameraSurfaceHolder = cameraSurfaceView.getHolder();
    cameraSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
//    cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.
  //                                               SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);




    btnCapture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capturebtn);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         camera.takePicture(cameraShutterCallback, 
                                       cameraPictureCallbackRaw,
                                       cameraPictureCallbackJpeg);
         isCaptured=true;
      }
    });
    btnsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             FrameLayout frm = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
                frm.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                frm.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = frm.getDrawingCache();
                try {
                    File rootFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/MYCAMERAOVERLAY");
                    rootFile.mkdirs();
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 10000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";

                    File resultingfile = new File(rootFile, fname);

                    if (resultingfile.exists ()) resultingfile.delete (); 
                    try {
                           FileOutputStream Fout = new FileOutputStream(resultingfile);
                           bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, Fout);
                           Fout.flush();
                           Fout.close();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
                }
                } catch(IOException e){
                    Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
                }
                isSaved=true;
            }
        });
    btnshare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
    btnshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if((isSaved)&&(isCaptured)){
                // TODO sharing what ever we saved 
                // take the path


            }

        }
    });
   } 


  ShutterCallback cameraShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() 
  {  
    @Override
    public void onShutter() 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    }
  };

  PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackRaw = new PictureCallback() 
  {  
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    }
  };

  PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackJpeg = new PictureCallback() 
  {  
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
      Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
                                                                  (data, 0, data.length);

   int   wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
     int  hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight();

    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wid+""+hgt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap
                                        (wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);

      canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

      camera.startPreview();

      newImage.recycle();
      newImage = null;

      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

      startActivity(intent);

    }
  };

  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, 
                                       int format, int width, int height) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(previewing)
    {
      camera.stopPreview();
      previewing = false;
    }
    try 
    {
      Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
      parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
      parameters.setPictureSize(640, 480);
      if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
          camera.setDisplayOrientation(-90);

      }

     // parameters.setRotation(90);
      camera.setParameters(parameters);

      camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceHolder);
      camera.startPreview();
      previewing = true;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
      camera = Camera.open();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e)
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device camera  is not working properly, please try after sometime.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try{


    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

}

and i think now i should give you the full XML part too. so here it is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/containerImg"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android1:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android1:gravity="bottom" >

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|top"
     >

 <SurfaceView
     android1:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
     android1:layout_width="100dip"
     android1:layout_height="150dip"
     android1:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ImageView
android1:id="@+id/imageView1"
android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
android1:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_dress_desc"
android:gravity="center|bottom"
android1:scaleType="center"
android1:src="@drawable/dress" />

</FrameLayout>


<GridLayout
    android1:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:columnCount="1"
    android1:gravity="center|bottom"
    android1:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android1:id="@+id/capturebtn"
        android1:layout_width="60dp"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_gravity="left"
        android1:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_icon_camera_desc" />

    <ImageButton
        android1:id="@+id/savebtn"
        android1:layout_width="60dp"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_column="0"
        android1:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android1:layout_row="0"
        android1:src="@drawable/save"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_icon_save_desc" />

    <ImageButton
        android1:id="@+id/sharebtn"
        android1:layout_width="60dp"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_column="0"
        android1:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android1:layout_row="0"
        android1:src="@drawable/share"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_icon_share_desc" />
</GridLayout>
```

share button doesn't work at this point but it saves the whole frame layout on capture clicked.
hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround alternative is to overlay the Activity XML file with another XML file which contains the header image. To do so:

1. Create a new Layout file inside the layout folder. For eg:
   `overlay.xml`
2. Insert an `ImageView` inside it, something like:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/android" />


   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. Then inside the Activity java file, ie `MotionDetector.java` file ,
   create a new method `addView()` :

   ```
      private void addView()
      {
          controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
          View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
          LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
          this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

      }
   ```
4. Finally invoke the `addView()` method from `onCreate()` to add the image:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.header);
   addView();
   ```

Then end result would be an image overlay above the `SurfaceView`. Subject to the quality of the header image, the rendered quality of the header shall seem original. Hope it helps.