# How to add watermark to the camera preview in android

Tags: android

I am using camera preview in my application.It should have a watermark while taking a photo and even after showing the preview also.It should also save the image with that watermark.

I just added Imageview, to show the image while taking photo.

```
     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/middle1">
  </FrameLayout>

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"

        android:background="@drawable/fblogo"  />
```

I can able to keep this image while taking photo and showing preview of image.But it is not saving this watermark.

I think it just working to show the image.How can I add this watermark to image even after taking the image.

This imageview I have added is just showing on my surfaceview,but the image is not saving with this watermark.only the image taken from camera is getting saved.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to make [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) from the photo taken, and then overlay watermark image on the canvas.

Try to the answer of Declan Shanaghy

[Android: How to overlay-a-bitmap/draw-over a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540272/android-how-to-overlay-a-bitmap-draw-over-a-bitmap)

Comment: I want to add the watermark when the camera gets opened.It should continue in preview and saved photo.How can I add image to surfaceview.

Comment: @user1871951 You have to implement two things for that. 1. Let the watermark image be floating on the camera preview. For this, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466336/android-overlay-on-android-camera-preview. 2. Even though you put overlay image on the camera preview, photos taken don't have watermark image on them. You should implement what I mentioned in the answer: make a canvas from the photo and overlay watermark image on it.

Comment: I need to set the canvas at particular position like this,   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 500, null); Did this effect on other devices of different size

Comment: @user1871951 It will depend on the size of the photo taken, which depends on the used device. I recommend you to use relative coordinates when putting the watermark image on the photo something like ``center of the image`` or ``30px less than the bottom right of the image``