# Outline of person's face on android camera

Tags: android, xml, android-camera, android-custom-view

I want to super-impose an outline of a face when the camera launches in android. Kind of like an empty avatar or a silhouette. I'm NOT looking for face detection. I just the want the user to have the ability to align the outline to the person's face when taking the picture, so that all pictures are taken at the same distance. I already have the camera launching. I'm thinking of putting the facial outline as my main layout and have the camera launching as the background of that layout. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466336/android-overlay-on-android-camera-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go
there is a section detailing how to do this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! I really appreciate it :)