# Android: Overlay Video on CameraView

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to show View from Camera and add transparent video on top of it. I don't want to save or record anything. I just want video to loop and show view from camera below it. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7466336/2522174

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks man, I will try it later and write feedback